# Drag and drop from right sidebar to left without deleting the draggable data

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a table of data on right sidebar. And I want to drop one of them to left panel, where I'have multiple textboxes and textarea. Here draggable item won't be deleted from right sidebar. How to achieve this using jquery?

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow! When posting a question, please share your code, and try to explain your problem as best as you can. Right now, it's very unclear what you are asking for.

Comment: 1. Share what you have tried. 2. You question is unclear. kindly update it with relevant info.

Comment: It will be similar to "wp all import" wordpress plugin

http://www.wpallimport.com/documentation/getting-started/importing-an-xml-or-csv-file/